# ZF2 Cron Job call to Model

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2

I am looking for help on ZF2 cron jobs. I will try to explain this the best I can. I am Fairly new with ZF2, sorry.
As a basic example, I have a cron job that runs through a list of active users. Currently the only way that works is recreating calls from my user model class, instead of reusing code already in place.

Example of work works

```
$this->usersTableGateway            = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('users', $dbAdapterTemp);
$users = $this->usersTableGateway->select(array('active' => 1));
```

This provides my users.

Why am I unable to use

```
if (!$this->usersTable) {
                $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                $this->usersTable = $sm->get('UserManagement\Model\UsersTable');
}
$this -> usersTable() -> getActiveUsers();
```

Is there a workaround for this for me to be able to call functions within my users model class? I am probably missing something really basic. I thought it had something to do with getServiceLocator but this statement works.

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

Thanks for the help in advance. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you declared 'UserManagement\Model\UsersTable' in your module.config.php ?

Comment: I have it declared in the users module.config.php. I never had to declare it in different parts of the application. Such as module->admin->controller->AdminCrontroller.php. I didn't have to add it to that parts module.config.php. Do I need to add it to the cron section since it is called from the console?

Comment: Actually, I only have controllers declared in module.config.php, I have it declared within Module.php. How would I declare UserManagement\Model\UsersTable, in module.config.php?

Comment: What is your error message ? Yes, ``UserManagement\Model\UsersTable`` can be declared in either ``Module.php`` or ``module.config.php``, depending on your choice. Into ``Module.php`` in ``getServiceConfig`` method. Into ``module.config.php``  in the return array by key ``'service_manager'=>[ 'invokables' =>['UserManagement\Model\UsersTable' => your_class::class]]`` if your constructor has no parameters, or ``'service_manager'=>[ 'factories' =>['UserManagement\Model\UsersTable' => your_factory::class]]``  else.